# Not Riemann integrable but uniform right hand rule converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Confused at this question, don't know where to start... Does anyone know?

For a bounded function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let $R_n = (1/n)\sum\limits_{j=1}^n f(j/n)$ which is the uniform right hand rule. Find an $f$ that is not Riemann integrable but $lim R_n$ exists.

Comment: dirichlet function which takes zero at rationals?

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic function of the rational numbers, a.k.a. Dirichlet function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Consider Dirichlet function which takes zero at rationals and one at irrationals